# I can not create a class instance from a string in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oop, php-8.1, symfony6

What I wanted to is to create class instance from string in Symfony framework to use Doctrine Repository. Here is my code block:

```
        $type = "SomeClassName";
        $productType = $this->productTypeProvider->getProductType($product->getBarcode());
    $repository = $this->doctrine->getRepository($type::class);
```

I want to use SomeClassName::class above but it gives me the following error. Any help would be appeciated:

```
Cannot use &quot;::class&quot; on value of type string (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: short answer is that you can't, but chances are that you don't want either -- what problem are you trying to actually solve with this? keep in mind, if you already have a class name, you can very simply `$this->doctrine->getRepository($classNameWithFqdn)`

Comment: @Federkun, I have only class name in this codeblock and I want to switch the repository depending on dynamic class name. If I try ->doctrine->getRepositry("SomeClassName"); it returns me the following error: Class SomeClassName does not exists (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: Did you try the full classname? e.g. `App\Entity\SomeClassName`

Comment: @craigh App\Entity\SomeClassName yes It worked perfectly. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, using the full class name worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To understand *why* this doesn't work, it's useful to have some background on how namespaces are implemented in PHP:

- Every class, interface, trait, and enum has a "fully-qualified class name" (FQCN), which can contain zero or more namespace separators (`\`)
- A particular file, or code-block, can have a "current namespace" defined.
- Within that block, you can have any number of `use` statements, which provide short-hands within the scope of that file.

The expansion of the current namespace, and the currently in-scope `use` statements, happens **at compile-time** - in case you're not aware, PHP is a compiled language, the compiler is just invoked automatically, for a single file.

The `::class` syntax is part of this compile-time expansion: it substitutes any relevant `use` statements or current namespace, and then treats the result as a string. In other words, this:

```php
namespace Foo\Bar;
use Something\Else;
use Something\Else\Again as Alias;

echo Example::class;
echo Else::class;
echo Else\More::class;
echo Alias::class;
```

Is compiled exactly as though it said this:

```
echo 'Foo\Bar\Example';
echo 'Something\Else';
echo 'Something\Else\More';
echo 'Something\Else\Again';
```

Those strings can then be passed around to wherever needs an FQCN.

The key point here is that this all happens **before any code in the file is executed**. When you tried to write `$type::class`, the value of `$type` is something that will only be known **at run-time**; far too late for the namespace expansion in the compiler to affect it. Theoretically, the compiler *could* know what you meant by `"SomeClassName"::class`, but it would be unnecessary extra complexity since you can just write `SomeClassName::class` instead.

If you are building a string at run-time, you are responsible for turning it into an FQCN.

Note that despite its name, `::class` doesn't actually check that the result is a class name, it just does string manipulation based on the current namespace and `use` statements, so the following are all equivalent:

```
namespace Example;

use App\Entity; // [1]
use App\Entity\SomeClassName; // [2]

// explicit FQCN
$type = 'App\Entity\SomeClassName';

// straight-forward expansion of [2]
$type = SomeClassName::class;

// expansion of [1]
$type = Entity\SomeClassName::class;

// expand the namespace via [1] then add class name
$namespace = Entity::class;
$type = $namespace . '\SomeClassName';

// expand to a non-existent class, then add more text
$prefix = Entity\So::class;
$type = $prefix . 'meClassName';
```